# React: How to remove an item from an array in useContext via reducer

Tags: reactjs

I've defined the initial state as below, and I've filled the `objectArray` with a few objects

```
const InitialState: StateInterface = {
  draw: 0,
  objects: {
    objectArray: [],
    selectedArray: [],
  },
  tools: {
    selector: false,
    snap: false,
  },
};
```

And I can add an object with

```
    case 'ADD_OBJECT':
      return {
        ...state,
        objects: {
          ...state.objects,
          objectArray: [...state.objects.objectArray, action.value],
        },
      };
```

The objects in the array looks like

`{name: 'selection', age:15, size'12'}, {name: 'selection', age:12, size'5'}`

I want to dispatch the object that I want to be deleted

`dispatch({ type: DELETE_OBJECT, value: {name: 'selection', age:15, size'12'} });`

I made the reducer

```
    case 'DELETE_OBJECT':
      return {
        ...state,
        objects: {
          ...state.objects,
          objectArray: [...state.objects.objectArray.pop(action.value)],
        },
      };
```

But I cant figure out how to remove the object contained in action.value from `objectArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are the same reference(which would probably be true) you can simply do

```js
objectArray: state.object.objectArray.filter(obj => obj !== action.value)
```

Or you can simply pass the index of the object in your action instead of the object itself

```js
objectArray: state.object.objectArray.filter((_, i) => i !== action.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter it out to return the other objects instead of the passed one:

```
objectArray: state.objects.objectArray.filter(obj => (obj.name !== action.value.name && obj.size !== action.value.size && obj.age !== action.value.age))]
```

`Array.prototype.filter()` method returns a new Array.

Answer (score 0):

Well a simple approach would just be to filter the array based on the given `value` object, e.g.

```
case 'DELETE_OBJECT':
    return {
    ...state,
        objects: {
          ...state.objects,
          objectArray: state.objects.objectArray.filter(obj => (
              obj.name !== action.value.name &&
              obj.age !== action.value.age &&
              obj.size !== action.value.size
          ))
    },
};
```

Or, if you're sure the properties will be in the same order:

```
case 'DELETE_OBJECT':
    return {
    ...state,
        objects: {
          ...state.objects,
          objectArray: state.objects.objectArray.filter(obj => (
              JSON.stringify(obj) !== JSON.stringify(action.value)
          ))
    },
};
```

If you have lodash, it has a function called `isEqual` that would also do this in an easy, robust way.

Your approach could be dangerous though, since none of your objects' properties seem to be unique identifiers, so filtering could lead to the removal of more than one object from the array. Just something to be aware of